How to Solve mujoco-py Installation Error Caused by Windows Path Length Limitation?
When using the OpenAI Gym HalfCheetah-v4 environment on windows, I encountered a path length limitation issue. The specific error is as follows:
could not create 'C:\Users\zchy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kf...File name too long
The screenshot:[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/FyvA5qWV.png)
Are there any solution I can try?
I have tried:
1.Move the project to a shorter path
2.Enable the long path

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Did you still have problems with the LongPathsEnabled = 0 register setting? If so, what specifically? And how about the shorter path for a project? I feel like with that setting in the register, it shouldn't be a problem

Thank you, my problem has already been solved.

If you'd like, you can post & accept your fix as an answer on this question. That way, if other people have the same problem as you, they can see what you did to fix it and try that themselves.
